# Abbreviated syntax for a C++11 enum class nested in a class?

Tags: c++11, enums, nested

I use a C++11 library which has a header with an enum class nested in a class:

```
class ClassWithARatherLongName
{
public:
    enum class EnumWithARatherLongName
    {
        VALUE1,
        VALUE2,
        VALUE3
    };
    (other code)
};
```

Then I use the enumerators in my code:

```
void foo()
{
    ... ClassWithARatherLongName::EnumWithARatherLongName::VALUE1 ...
}
```

This works, but is tedious. Isn't there a way to abbreviate the syntax?

Ideally, I would like to be able to write something like:

```
void foo()
{
    (some directive that allows to use an abbreviated syntax)
    ... VALUE1 ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `typedef` or `using` to create a "shortcut":

```
using E = ClassWithARatherLongName::EnumWithARatherLongName;
E::VALUE1
```

Comment: Almost as short as what I was hoping for. If there is a way to get rid of the `E::`, it's even better.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a typedef:

```
void foo()
{
    typedef ClassWithARatherLongName::EnumWithARatherLongName e;
    e::VALUE1
}
```

You might be able to shorten the names, by using namespaces.