# Abbreviated Syntax to define a std::vector of class enum values in C++

Tags: c++, enums

Due to my inability to find an answer or the right words to search for I ask here:

I have a (lengthy) class enum defined by

```cpp
enum class SomeLongName { Foo = 1, Bar = 7, FooBar = 42 };
```

The only way I know to define a vector of those is:

```cpp
#include <vector>

enum class SomeLongName { Foo = 1, Bar = 7, FooBar = 42 };

int main() {
  std::vector<SomeLongName> v1 = {
    SomeLongName::Foo,
    SomeLongName::FooBar
  };
  return 0;
}
```

**Is there a way (alternative abbreviated syntax) to use a `class enum` and don't need to rewrite `SomeLongName::` for each value independently?** e.g. something like (not working)

```cpp
#include <vector>

enum class SomeLongName { Foo = 1, Bar = 7, FooBar = 42 };

int main() {
  std::vector<SomeLongName> v1 = (SomeLongName::) { Foo , Bar };
  return 0;
}
```

In case this matters: I am using MSVC 2019, amd64 (64bit), C++17 on windows 10 64bit

**Note:** using a typedef like suggested in [this stackoverflow discussion thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32934594/abbreviated-syntax-for-a-c11-enum-class-nested-in-a-class) is not actually what I want or am asking for

Comment: http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1099r4.html

Comment: Pre-C++20 `using enum SomeLongName;`, you can also use a function local `using E = SomeLongName;` to shorten the name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++20 added using enum X syntax, which does what it looks like.

```
#include <vector>

enum class SomeLongName { Foo = 1, Bar = 7, FooBar = 42 };

int main()
{
    using enum SomeLongName;
    std::vector<SomeLongName> v1 = { Foo, Bar };
    return 0;
}
```

In previous versions, you can use an enum instead of an enum class.

Comment: Ah thanks that looks promising. I found it both in the [msvc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019) and general [c++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support)  supported features per compiler overview being supported by msvc 2019 16.4. But eventhough I have version 16.7 installed I get compiler error (`An identifier was expected` translated from German) for `using enum SomeLongName;`, when building via cmake using `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)` and `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)`

Comment: You are welcome. I have tried on Visual Studio 16.9.4. Building via CMake using set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20) passed successfully. I suppose you need to update your VS.

Answer (score 2):

Pre C++20: Unfortunately no. Its a "feature" of scoped enums that you have to prepend the name of the enum type. However, before scoped enums were a thing, it was common to wrap enums in a class to avoid polluting the namespace. You can still do that:

```
#include <vector>

struct SomeLongName {
    enum values { Foo = 1,Bar = 7, FooBar = 42};

    static std::vector<values> make_vect() {
        return {Foo,FooBar};
    }
};

int main() {
    auto v = SomeLongName::make_vect();
}
```

It's not "nice" but it works.

Past C++20: I refer you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67500914/4117728).

Comment: This is indeed not very "nice" and actually also more overhead, and worse to read (i think). But still thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Martin the "overhead" is only poor style. If thats the only way and you absolutely want it, I wouldnt consider it too bad to sacrifice a bit of style

Comment: true, but I don't need it that urgent :)